# get methods of an object in ruby

Tags: ruby, reflection

I'm a little confused about this behavior from the ruby (1.9) interpreter

```
 class Foo
   def pub
     private_thing
   end

   private
   def private_thing
     puts "private touch"
   end
 end



x = Foo.new
x.pub
private touch
=> nil
```

so far so good.

```
x.private_thing
NoMethodError: private method `private_thing' called for #<Foo:0xb76abd34>
from (irb):25
from :0
```

still ok. that's what I expected

but why is this empty?

```
x.methods(false)
=> []
```

while this gives me what I was expecting?

```
Foo.instance_methods(false)
=> ["pub"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, the "methods" method seems to have disappeared. You should use [public_instance_methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Module.html#method-i-public_instance_methods) instead.

To explain why that `x.methods(false)` is behaving that way, look back at ruby 1.9.1 docs http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/Object.html#method-i-methods. If you see the source code if you pass in a parameter it behaves as singleton_methods, which is what you're seing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no documentation for Object#methods beyond ruby 1.9.1. As if it no longer exists. (take a look http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html)

I suppose this is to clarify that one should be using one of .singleton_methods or .instance_methods to determine where methods live.

In any case, an undocumented method can do whatever it likes.